# jQuery ternary for setting option value selected by default

Tags: jquery, ternary-operator

Inside of an `.each` I am using a`.map` to assemble the guts of a select input. Everything is working just fine. I would however, like to set the select attribute if a given value is the same.

**jQuery:**

```
return '<option value="' + item.itemID + '"' + (item.itemID === thing.itemID) ? 'selected="selected"' : '' + '>' + item.itemDesc+ '</option>';
```

That's what I'm trying to accomplish, but that obviously doesn't work. I *could* do an old-school "if" but I'm trying not to duplicate myself.

I am close, but no cigar. This: `(item.itemID === thing.itemID)` returns `true`. Just can't seem to put the pieces together for some reason.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Try: `(item.itemID===thing.itemID ? 'selected="selected"' : '')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
return '<option value="' + item.itemID + '"' + 
       (item.itemID === thing.itemID ? 'selected="selected"' : '') +
       '>' + item.itemDesc+ '</option>';
```

Comment: This worked great. The difference was that you surrounded the entire ternary in parenthesis?

Comment: Yes -- I think that in your original code, everything after `:` was seen as part of the "else" statement. That's how I would have read it, anyway.

Comment: That's what was happening, everything was coming back as `true`. Should have walked away & came back I guess. Thank you very much!